# mudei o background do botão e parou o efeito de ação

Tags: android, xml

alterei o background do meu button para `#000000` (preto) e parou de realizar a demonstração do click (ficava azul quando clicava)

```
<Button
   android:id="@+id/btNext2"
   android:layout_width="0dp"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:layout_weight="1"
   android:text="@string/Next"
   android:textSize="30sp"
   android:background="#000000"
   android:textColor="#ffffff"/>
```

Comment: Bem Vindo ao [StackOverFlow em Português](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/). No método onClick foi feita alguma alteração?

Answer (score 3):

Você precisa de um `selector` nesse *background* para ter os estados do botão, e não simplesmente uma cor sólida. Crie um arquivo **btn_selector.xml** no seu diretório **drawable** e faça algo assim:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/darker_gray" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/black"/>
</selector>
```

E na propriedade `background` do botão:

```
android:background="@drawable/btn_selector"
```